# Allowing script to function with SESSION authentication

Tags: php, sqlite, session, session-storage

I have a php script where if the entry into the textbox form matches with anything in the database then create a session:

```
 $name= $_POST['name']; 

 $db= new  PDO('sqlite:people.db'); 
 $query = "SELECT * from names WHERE name= '$name'";
 $results = $db->Query($query)->fetchAll(); 

 $allow= count($results); 

 if ( $table  > 0 )
    {
    session_start();
    $enable= 1;
    $_SESSION['enabled'] = $enable;
    }
```

the other script is like:

```
 if (isset($_SESSION))
{

 $code= $_POST['code']; 
 $db= new  PDO('sqlite:Properties1.db'); 
 $query = "SELECT * from properties WHERE postcode = '$postcode'";
 $results = $db->Query($query)->fetchAll(); //fetchAll puts results into an array

  $allow= count($results); //count the rows in the results array

 if ( $rowcount > 0 )
 {
 do this
 }
```

But the second script does not pick up the session

Comment: Debug and make sure `session_start` is actually getting called.

Comment: what is $table and $rowcount?

Answer (score 0):

`if (isset($_SESSION))` this will always return 1 and if condition will always execute. Because `$_SESSION` is **super global** and its always set through out the script.

Try checking it as below,

```
if (isset($_SESSION['enabled']))
{
```

Comment: do you have to use cookie aswell because i didnt put that